# raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg)) TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phone'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created one table attribute phone in auth_user manually (if i remove phone attribute it work fine) but when I add `phone` it gives  error.

I tried everything but its not working is it really good way to store data in django

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == "POST": 

    firstName = request.POST.get('firstName', None)
    lastName = request.POST.get('lastName', None)
    username = request.POST.get('username',None)
    email = request.POST.get('email', None)
    mobileNumber = request.POST.get('mobileNumber',None)
    password = request.POST.get('password', None)
    user=User.objects.create_user(
        first_name = firstName,
        last_name = lastName, 
        username = username, 
        email = email, 
        phone = mobileNumber,
        password = password

    )
    user.save()

    return HttpResponse('Succesfully user created')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Django doesn't know that you have added an extra field to the table. Django gets these informations from the `models.py` and the `migrations` files.

Instead of adding a `phone` field manually into the `auth_user` table it is preferred that you always use a custom `User` model in your projects to easily customize your `User` model. [Extending User model Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

1. Create a Custom User model

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

2. Update your `settings` file

```py
# Here app_name is the name of the app
# inside which you created the User model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<app_name>.User'
```

3. Use the `User` model by importing from that particular file or by using `get_user_model` function available in `django`.

Comment: Do i need to override BaseUserManager also in models.